# Angular2 calling function inside iteration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have small problem with angular2. I am using nativescript and mapbox plug-in. When I add markers through iteration (subscribe of service) onTap method don't do anything. But when it is out of iteration (alone) it works. Mayen I don't understant some angular logic, but I tried almost everything.

```
      this.pointsService.getPoints().subscribe(points => {
    this.points = points;
    let markers = [];
    for (let point of this.points) {
      markers.push({
        id: point['id'],
        lat: point['lat'],
        lng: point['lng'],
        title: 'test_' + point['id'],
        onTap: () => {console.log("tap event" + point['id'])}
      });
    }
    this.mapboxMap.addMarkers(markers);
   });
```

Here is full repository https://github.com/b4rtt/nativescript_markers

Comment: Have you tried defining a method outside? `onTapMethod(pointId) { console.log("tap event" + pointId) }` and `onTap: () => this.onTapMethod(point['id'])` or maybe w/o the setter `onTap: this.onTapMethod(point['id'])`

Comment: try adding var that =  this; before promise call and then call fucntion as that.functionName();